# How to save axios request in vue.js store correclty?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I would like to create dynamic sidebar links pulled from an API.
This is the theme I'm working with:
https://admin.vuebulma.com/#/

Note the charts link that has a list of children in the sidebar..

I want to make an API request - lets say for charts and create each child (see charts.js) for each element return in the API request.

In the example below, the data objects are hardcoded - I would like to remove this and dynamically create each child using a for loop for each element in the api request.body

## /store/modules/menu/index.js

```
import * as types from '../../mutation-types'
import lazyLoading from './lazyLoading'
import charts from './charts'
import components from './components'
import dashboard from './dashboard'

// show: meta.label -> name
// name: component name
// meta.label: display label

const state = {
  items: [
    dashboard,
    charts,
    components
  ]
}

const mutations = {
  [types.EXPAND_MENU] (state, menuItem) {
    if (menuItem.index > -1) {
      if (state.items[menuItem.index] && state.items[menuItem.index].meta) {
        state.items[menuItem.index].meta.expanded = menuItem.expanded
      }
    } else if (menuItem.item && 'expanded' in menuItem.item.meta) {
      menuItem.item.meta.expanded = menuItem.expanded
    }
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  mutations
}
```

## /store/modules/menu/charts.js

```
import lazyLoading from './lazyLoading'

export default {
  name: 'Charts',
  path: '/charts',
  meta: {
    icon: 'fa-bar-chart-o',
    expanded: false,
    link: 'charts/index.vue'
  },
  component: lazyLoading('charts', true),

  children: [
    {
      name: 'Chartist',
      path: 'chartist',
      component: lazyLoading('charts/Chartist'),
      meta: {
        link: 'charts/Chartist.vue'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Chartjs',
      path: 'chartjs',
      component: lazyLoading('charts/Chartjs'),
      meta: {
        link: 'charts/Chartjs.vue'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Peity',
      path: 'peity',
      component: lazyLoading('charts/Peity'),
      meta: {
        link: 'charts/Peity.vue'
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Plotly',
      path: 'plotly',
      component: lazyLoading('charts/Plotly'),
      meta: {
        link: 'charts/Plotly.vue'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## sidebar.vue

```
<template>
  <aside class="menu app-sidebar animated" :class="{ slideInLeft: show, slideOutLeft: !show }">
    <p class="menu-label">
      General
    </p>
    <ul class="menu-list">
      <li v-for="(item, index) in menu">
        <router-link :to="item.path" :exact="true" :aria-expanded="isExpanded(item) ? 'true' : 'false'" v-if="item.path" @click.native="toggle(index, item)">
          <span class="icon is-small"><i :class="['fa', item.meta.icon]"></i></span>
          {{ item.meta.label || item.name }}
          <span class="icon is-small is-angle" v-if="item.children && item.children.length">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
          </span>
        </router-link>
        <a :aria-expanded="isExpanded(item)" v-else @click="toggle(index, item)">
          <span class="icon is-small"><i :class="['fa', item.meta.icon]"></i></span>
          {{ item.meta.label || item.name }}
          <span class="icon is-small is-angle" v-if="item.children && item.children.length">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
          </span>
        </a>

        <expanding v-if="item.children && item.children.length">
          <ul v-show="isExpanded(item)">
            <li v-for="subItem in item.children" v-if="subItem.path">
              <router-link :to="generatePath(item, subItem)">
                {{ subItem.meta && subItem.meta.label || subItem.name }}
              </router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </expanding>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</template>

<script>
import Expanding from 'vue-bulma-expanding'
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  components: {
    Expanding
  },

  props: {
    show: Boolean
  },

  data () {
    return {
      isReady: false
    }
  },

  mounted () {
    let route = this.$route
    if (route.name) {
      this.isReady = true
      this.shouldExpandMatchItem(route)
    }
  },

  computed: mapGetters({
    menu: 'menuitems'
  }),

  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'expandMenu'
    ]),

    isExpanded (item) {
      return item.meta.expanded
    },

    toggle (index, item) {
      this.expandMenu({
        index: index,
        expanded: !item.meta.expanded
      })
    },

    shouldExpandMatchItem (route) {
      let matched = route.matched
      let lastMatched = matched[matched.length - 1]
      let parent = lastMatched.parent || lastMatched
      const isParent = parent === lastMatched

      if (isParent) {
        const p = this.findParentFromMenu(route)
        if (p) {
          parent = p
        }
      }

      if ('expanded' in parent.meta && !isParent) {
        this.expandMenu({
          item: parent,
          expanded: true
        })
      }
    },

    generatePath (item, subItem) {
      return `${item.component ? item.path + '/' : ''}${subItem.path}`
    },

    findParentFromMenu (route) {
      const menu = this.menu
      for (let i = 0, l = menu.length; i < l; i++) {
        const item = menu[i]
        const k = item.children && item.children.length
        if (k) {
          for (let j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            if (item.children[j].name === route.name) {
              return item
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  watch: {
    $route (route) {
      this.isReady = true
      this.shouldExpandMatchItem(route)
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Not sure why I can't figure out how to do this.

Update:

Here's an example of the API I'm calling:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "os": "windows",
        "url": "https://test.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "os": "ios",
        "url": "https://test.com"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test3",
        "os": "windows",
        "url": "https://test.com"
    },
]
```

Comment: What does the response from the API request look like?

Comment: Mutations aren't asynchronous.  If you need to perform an asynchronous operation, you should always do it in an action and then commit a mutation to store the data after the promise has resolved.  https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html

Comment: so mutation is required right

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a copy of routes of charts in `store`

   ```
   const state = {
     chartsRoutes: []
   }
   ```
2. Create a `computed` property in component

   ```
   computed: {
     chartsRoutes () {
       return this.$store.state.chartsRoutes
     }
   }
   ```
3. Use `v-for` to render `chartsRoutes` into `router-link`s in component
4. Create a mutation to modify store and router

   ```
   // import router
   const mutations = {
     'update-charts-routes': function (state, payload) {
       const { chartsRoutes } = payload
       state.chartsRoutes = chartsRoutes.map(r => {
         return {
           path: '/your/custom/path/according/to/response'
           // other params
         }
       })
       router.addRoutes(state.chartsRoutes)
     }
   }
   ```
5. Create an action

   ```
   const actions = {
     'reload-charts': function ({commit, dispatch}, data) {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         const r = {
           method: 'get',
           url: data.url,
           // add more options, e.g. header or auth
         }
         axios.request(r)
           .then(resp => {
             commit('update-charts-routes', { chartsRoutes: resp.data })
             resolve()
           })
           .catch(err => {
             // handle error
             reject(err)
           })
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
6. Dispatch action

   ```
   this.$store.dispatch('reload-charts', { url: 'http://some.host/path/to/url' })
     .then(() => {
       // other stuff
     })
   ```